# Integrating Unity with Eclipse - Communication?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, unity-game-engine

I made it by following steps: [Integrating Unity and Eclipse](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/71607-Integrating-Unity-and-Eclipse). Can I call functions (that I created with JavaScript or C# in Unity) with the Android SDK or NDK and the other way around? There are an interface between UnityPlayer and Android SDK or NDK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For whom this may help:

As @Oli mentioned, you can communicate between Unity and an Android app by using this method:

```
UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("GameObjectName1", "MethodName1", "Message to send");
```

In order for this method to work, you must follow this guide: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/71607-Integrating-Unity-and-Eclipse

You can also call Java methods from Unity C# file - http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Plugins.html

You can use this code in order to start the Unity app after you add it as library to your Android project:

```
UnityPlayer mPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this); // Put your activity object here
    int glesMode = mPlayer.getSettings().getInt("gles_mode", 1);
    boolean trueColor8888 = false;
    mPlayer.init(glesMode, trueColor8888);
```

Hope this helps anyone... I've researched a lot until I found this information.

Answer (score 0):

No, You can't call JavaScript or C# functions in Eclipse , On the contrary you can use native android functions in unity3d by integrating Unity with Eclipse.

Comment: Do you have an example (a function call)?

Comment: http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Android-Integrating%20Unity%20With%20Eclipse.html

Comment: It is still possible to call C# functions in Eclipse with

UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("GameObjectName1", "MethodName1", "Message to send");