# Call function C# in Java with unity Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

i want call function C# in java with unity,
Help me!

NOT!: Call java in C# :

```
AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        AndroidJavaObject jo = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        jo.Call("Buy2");
```

I want to do the opposite

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("GameObjectName1", "MethodName1", "Message to send");
```

Detail from here: [Integrating Unity with Eclipse - Communication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159976/integrating-unity-with-eclipse-communication)

Comment: tks @Frank Nguyễn !
 but it's not working, you can example for me,
I do not understand